# Display data in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, jpa, html-table

I need to manually display data from database in jsp page. But it wont display.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Contact.getAll", query="SELECT c FROM Contact c") 
public class Contact implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
private String login;
private String name;
private String surname;

getters/setters/equals/hashcode
```

Bean to manage jsp:

```
public class DisplayDataBean {

private EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ContactsPU");
private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
private List<Contact> contacts = em.createNamedQuery("Contact.getAll", Contact.class).getResultList();

public List<Contact> getContacts() {
    return contacts;
}
}
```

And jsp page fragment:

```
        <c:forEach var="contact" items="${DisplayDataBean.contacts}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.login}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.name}"/></td>
                <td><c:out value="${contact.surname}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Can you please tell what can be wrong in here? Thanks in advance.

Also when i work with

```
<sql:query var="contacts" dataSource="jdbc/contactapplication">
    SELECT * FROM contact;
</sql:query>
```

everything is fine.

Problem was that i didnt declare DisplayDataBean. 
Solution is to add tag in jsp page:

```
<jsp:useBean id="displayBean" class="web.DisplayDataBean"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not declaring the variable `contacts` so that it is not showing, when you are using JSTL tag then you are using variable `contacts`.

I you are using Spring then please add this `contacts` variable to `ModelMap` so that it can be retrieve.

```
ModelMap mm = new ModelMap();
mm.put("contacts", values);
```

Or if you are using Servlet then just add this variable to response parameter.
`request.setAttribute("contacts", "value");`

Comment: Well i dont use either Spring nor servlets. It is just 3 files. And attribute items should get list of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to provide a physical table name to your entity. I think case sensitivity may cause problems here ("contact" and "Contact" aren't necessarily considered the same).

Also, I'm not 100% sure, but the `@NamedQuery` may need to be enclosed into `@NamedQueries` - so the entity definition could start like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="contact")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Contact.getAll", query="SELECT c FROM Contact c")
})
public class Contact implements Serializable {
// the rest of the class definition goes here...
```

If you have debugging enabled, you may be able to see if the query was actually issued or if it "failed" even before that.

By the way, when you say "it won't display", does it mean nothing is rendered by `c:forEach`? Does it render empty table, nulls or nothing at all? Example of the generated output could help.

I assume there are no exceptions visible in the console/log?

Comment: Yeah it rendered empty table.